Was it God the Father or Pre-Incarnate Christ in Genesis
In Genesis 3:8, they heard the footsteps/ or God walking in the cool of the day? Is there any evidence to suggest that this is analogous since God is spirit or physicality of the pre-incarnate Christ?
Hope this makes sense 

Appropriate This question is appropriate for BH.SE because is seeks an exposition of a specific verse: Whether it is a voice from God, or a manifestation of a theophany of Jesus (pre-incarnate). The Hebrew syntax might help in deciding whether "walking" referred to God (Jesus) or to Adam (who was hearing a voice).

Let me first say that ray grant gave a very good answer. Having said that I would like to add some points. In the New Testament we have Jesus Christ Himself stating at John 5:37, "And the Father Himself, who sent Me, has testified of Me. You have neither heard His voice at any time, nor seen His form." (Obviously these verses refer to the Father.)
Jesus also said at John 6:46, "Not that any man hath seen the Father, except he who is from God, he hath seen the Father." Then there is the 1 John 4:12, "No one has beheld God at any time; if we love one another, God abides in us, and His love is perfected in us."
Now, the reason I brought these verses up was to show that the Father has no separate manifestation from the Son. The Son is the only manifestation and revelation of the Father. What is known of the Father is revealed through the Son. To see the Son is to see the essence/nature of the Father (John 1:1:18, 10:30; 12:45; Colossians 1:15; Hebrews 1:3). This is verified at John 14:5-18 when Jesus has a discussion with Philip.
So how is this displayed in the Old Testament? How do we determine who appeared and who is speaking in the Old Testament? One example can be found at Genesis 17:1-3, "Now when Abram was ninety-nine years old, the Lord appeared to Abram and said to him, "I am God Almighty; Walk before Me, and be blameless. VS2, And I will establish My covenant between Me and you, And I will multiply you exceedingly. Vs3, "And Abram fell on his face, and God talked with him:"
So, how do we know this was a physical appearance? (Remember God the Father cannot be seen). Genesis 17:22, "And when He/God finished talking with him, God went up from Abraham." Now look at Genesis 18:1-5, "Now the Lord appeared to him/Abraham by the oaks of Mamre, while he was sitting at the tent door in the heat of the day." You can read the rest of the verses which show Abraham offering bread and water. There were three men who appeared to Abraham. One of them was the pre-incarnate Jesus Christ know in the OT as the "Angel of the Lord." and two actual angels.
I could give many more examples of the Angel of the Lord appearing to OT saints and some of them identified the Angel of the Lord as God Himself.

the Angel of the Lord cannot be God Himself as only the ‘one true God’, the Father is immortal. The angel is a representative of God as was Jesus.

Please vote to close duplicate questions rather than answering them.

Excellent QuestionThe grand revelation confirmed both in the Old Testament (Tanakh) and the New Testament is that God is a Spirit, and they that worship Him must worship in spirit and in truth. (John 4:24)
But the quandary arises in our minds when the Old Testament portrays incidents when God talks, or seems to show up in some form, physical in nature. Sometimes this form is called the Angel of the Lord. And when it is God speaking down from heaven, He uses a common voice that a physical ear can hear plainly.
So how can this be explained?It is true that the eternal substance and essence of God is Spirit, and thus "invisible." In His everlasting nature, God is spirit, and it is necessarily so since it is only spirit that does not fade away or deteriorate. Things physical are subject to decay.
But in His time and ineffable wisdom, God created things "physical." And there are times when He interacts, interjects, (interferes), with that which He has made.  And He can do that, since He has control over every aspect of His creation.

The hearing ear, and the seeing eye, the LORD has made them both. (Proverbs 20:12)

So, to carry out His amazing plan of Salvation and Redemption of Fallen Man, God will take the initiative to speak to prophets and on to mankind through the prophets. God will at times even speak directly (consider Mt. Sinai experience).
And at times, God will take on the physical form of the man He has created, often so glorious that He seems like an angel! Hence in that event He is called "the Angel of the Lord."
Such is the type of manifestation in the Garden of Eden: The voice of God walking the cool of the day (Genesis 3:8).The way the scripture is worded some may take the words to mean that "Adam and Eve were walking" while others may take it to mean "God...walking in the garden." Either way, the Voice of God was heard.
If taken to be a physical Presence, there is nothing prohibiting it being called a manifestation of the Preincarnate Christ. Just as Abraham saw stranger visitors approaching him in the plains of Mamre (just before the destruction of Sodom; Genesis 18 the Lord appeared unto him.)
Important CaveatIn all these discussions, it should definitely be kept in the forefront of our scholarly minds that the Father and the Son (Jesus) are One! (See Deuteronomy 6:4, 1 John 5:7) Manifestations of Jesus in the Old Testament are manifestations of the eternal God (temporarily wrapped in human flesh, for aid to help in our ability to grasp Him and understand His ways.)

Please vote to close duplicate questions rather than answering them.

@curiousdannii Will do so in future. However, I thought I gave this answer before I knew it was a duplicate.  You're doing a good job! Peace.


“And they heard the voice of the LORD God walking in the garden in the cool of the day: and Adam and his wife hid themselves from the presence of the LORD God amongst the trees of the garden. And the LORD God called unto Adam, and said unto him, Where art thou?” (Gen 3:8-9, KJV)

Literal interpretation
Certain things are stated in the two verses quoted above:

They heard a voice. The Hebrew word translated as 'heard' is שׁמע. It means  'A careful hearing of someone or something as well as responding appropriately in obedience or action.' It means 'to hear (perceive by ear)' according to Brown-Driver-Briggs definition. If this is taken literally, they heard a voice with their ears.

They heard footsteps in the garden. It seemed they were familiar footsteps they were used to but their response changed. The voice they heard and the 'walk in the garden' created fear in them.

They knew who it was. They recognised the voice and the walk. If there was a literal walk in the garden, this was a walk by someone who was limited and confined to time and space. Here, omnipresence is not expressed.

God asked a question, "Where art thou?". God in his omniscience definitely knew what had happened and where they were but the question did not portend omniscience. God came to them possibly because he knew what happened as well as coming to visit them as usual because Adam and Eve knew it was God. However, God did not appear to them in his divinity. I do not believe that God, in this scene, pretended not to know where they were. I believe, on the face value of the question that there was limited knowledge expressed here. This limited knowledge portends that this person is not in his full divine state.


Summary
From the points I have listed above, The LORD God in verse 8 does not look like God in his divine form. Jesus defined or described God in John 4:24 saying "God is a Spirit...". The attributes of God in his divinity obviously, do not fit the '...walking in the garden...' as well as the question.
An expression closely similar to this scene but with a different response is found in Gen.18:1-2.

“And the LORD appeared unto him in the plains of Mamre: and he sat in the tent door in the heat of the day; And he lift up his eyes and looked, and, lo, three men stood by him: and when he saw them, he ran to meet them from the tent door, and bowed himself toward the ground,” (Gen 18:1-2, KJV)

Here, God did not appear to Abram in his full divinity. Abraham saw three men and God was one of them.
Other possible interpretation:
The only other possible interpretation I can think of is that Adam and Eve heard God in their conscience/heart if we interpret the LORD God as God in his divine state or full glory. This line of interpretation raises some questions. Did they hear God's voice in their conscience or heart? Did they hear God walking in the garden by their conscience or heart? Did they hear God call them by their names in their conscience or heart?
If this is so, It will lead to complications. Did God curse them in their conscience? Did the events in Gen.3:14-19 take place in their conscience or heart? How were Adam and Eve driven out of the garden by their conscience? How did they see the event in verse 24?
Hence, it shows that interpretation based on conscience is complicated. I reject this.
Conclusion:
Based on the literal interpretation, this can only be Christophany.

Christophany By the very nature of the incarnate (or pre-incarnate) Christ, there is a limitation of the eternality and divine attributes of God.  The physical gets in the way, so to speak.  Whereas a "theophany" would experience no limitations. So, can it be determined by the Hebrew syntax whether we have a Theophany or a Christophany here?

@ Boavintura Ferreira God often asks question in the Bible, with full divinity omniscience, not because He doesn't know, but because He wants the person to come out and acknowledge his condition or sin or need for His help! The questions are for the benefit of the perpetrator (or believer in need). See how Jesus dialogued with people in the NT.

@raygrant. Thank you for the comment. I fully agree it is Christophany. I will change the word.
